# IronPdf - How to make headers and footers not cover page content when converting HTML to PDF?

Tags: c#, .net-core, pdf-generation, html-to-pdf, ironpdf

I am using IronPdf to generate Pdf files from HTML content and the issue I have is that when I try to add headers and footers to the document they cover some of the page contents.
I know that I can set page margins in the size of header and footer height to fix this issue but in my case I have to use different headers and footers for different pages(Ex: First page has a different header from others, last page footer is different from others).

Edit: After I spoke with the IronPdf support it seems that currently there is no direct and clean way to achieve the required result. They say that a feature that allows you to set different margins for each page (which would solve this case) is in the development queue but it will take time for it to be finished.

Answer (score 1):

I work for Iron software support.

Header/footer content will override content of the PDF if there isn't enough space for it. Currently it's not possible to set different margins for different pages within the same PDF, though this is bering looked at for a future feature.

As a workaround you may create separate PDFs then merge them together.

```
// Join Multiple Existing PDFs into a single document
var PDFs     = new List<PdfDocument>();
PDFs.Add(PdfDocument.FromFile("A.pdf"));
PDFs.Add(PdfDocument.FromFile("B.pdf"));
PDFs.Add(PdfDocument.FromFile("C.pdf"));
PdfDocument PDF =  PdfDocument.Merge(PDFs);
PDF.SaveAs("merged.pdf");
```

Code example taken from: [Editing PDFs in C# with IronPDF](https://ironpdf.com/examples/editing-pdfs/)

Alternatively you can set margins in the HTML and use the following code example:

```
var Renderer = new ChromePdfRenderer();
Renderer.RenderingOptions.MarginTop = 5;
Renderer.RenderingOptions.MarginBottom = 5;
Renderer.RenderingOptions.MarginLeft = 5;
Renderer.RenderingOptions.MarginRight = 5;
var pdf =Renderer.RenderHtmlFileAsPdf(@"F:\body.html");

var CoverPageheader = new HtmlHeaderFooter();
CoverPageheader.HtmlFragment = "<div style='color:red; font-size:15px;font-weight:bold;'>Hello world </div>";

var header = new HtmlHeaderFooter();
header.HtmlFragment = "<div style='color:red; font-size:15px;font-weight:bold;'>other pages Header... <br> My Header </div>";

pdf.AddHTMLHeaders(header,true);
pdf.AddHTMLHeaders(CoverPageheader, false, new List<int>{ 0 });

pdf.SaveAs(@"F:\output.pdf");
```

Using the edited HTML below:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div> this is the cover page</div>
<div style="page-break-before: always; margin-top: 40px;">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut dictum sapien at odio ullamcorper efficitur. Nam luctus tortor enim, id consequat ex scelerisque vel. Duis vulputate, sem et faucibus auctor, diam nisi fermentum risus, a viverra purus magna nec lorem. Cras efficitur vehicula elit, et suscipit sem varius vestibulum. Etiam et laoreet augue. Etiam nulla magna, molestie nec efficitur sed, dignissim placerat felis. Fusce posuere dignissim nunc, vitae rutrum nunc tristique id. Sed molestie mi nunc, eget molestie augue sollicitudin a. Phasellus et porttitor libero. Integer ac dolor quis libero posuere varius in sit amet nisl. Maecenas ac metus a sapien bibendum malesuada in eget diam. Donec facilisis mi vel tortor pulvinar gravida. Aenean auctor nisi et augue facilisis, pellentesque blandit augue malesuada. Etiam eu ipsum a nunc vehicula pellentesque id ac metus. Fusce tincidunt sed urna in hendrerit.

Nam feugiat et nisl ac consectetur. Nunc in tellus volutpat, pulvinar libero vitae, congue orci. Aenean sit amet porta odio. Integer enim ex, maximus vitae erat sit amet, lobortis aliquam enim. Ut at odio nec eros ornare bibendum. In eget urna molestie ante mattis elementum. Mauris id sodales quam, non aliquam quam. Mauris justo nulla, varius in libero eu, interdum convallis eros. Nam efficitur ornare neque non convallis. Donec massa orci, auctor id fringilla eget, aliquet in leo. Morbi at aliquet nisl, eget commodo neque. Vestibulum vestibulum mattis neque, eget porta lorem pellentesque cursus.

Proin quis lacus in leo consequat gravida. Aenean sed ornare arcu, vel rutrum mauris. Ut arcu lacus, tincidunt a enim et, commodo elementum mi. Donec metus neque, feugiat vitae commodo eget, ullamcorper vehicula lorem. Nunc tincidunt velit sapien, id commodo lacus pretium eu. Aliquam massa tellus, ultricies ac fermentum in, cursus eu ante. Suspendisse a augue pretium, posuere nibh id, vulputate tellus. Nunc vehicula orci ac nibh sagittis tincidunt. Morbi tempus ultricies turpis, eu ullamcorper nisi.

Cras ornare dignissim felis eu tristique. Quisque aliquam magna sed nisi ultricies placerat. Proin fringilla, quam viverra consequat interdum, mauris ex malesuada sapien, id venenatis ante felis eu odio. Donec ultrices consectetur varius. Ut vel odio lorem. Aliquam condimentum tempor tristique. Proin a risus malesuada, efficitur urna at, lacinia nibh. Pellentesque consequat vulputate lorem vitae tincidunt. Proin eu congue felis, venenatis ornare elit. Etiam at nulla quis enim maximus fermentum sit amet eu dui. Morbi vel tellus eu mauris tincidunt placerat vel laoreet magna. Morbi sit amet est sit amet libero auctor accumsan. Integer ut nulla at eros volutpat euismod. Ut ullamcorper porttitor porta.

Aliquam varius velit eget enim hendrerit convallis. Suspendisse sed faucibus nisi. Nulla rhoncus orci nulla, quis pellentesque dolor sollicitudin ac. Aenean ac tincidunt turpis. Vivamus interdum dolor nec sem gravida euismod. Vestibulum blandit erat nunc, vel gravida lacus lacinia eget. Morbi faucibus purus fermentum, faucibus libero sit amet, semper tellus. Integer molestie quam nec purus tristique, et tincidunt augue hendrerit. Proin sit amet dui in nulla vestibulum mattis et euismod nulla. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vivamus nisi sapien, faucibus ut tincidunt nec, rutrum in sem. Phasellus iaculis, ipsum eu ultricies fringilla, ligula felis imperdiet odio, vel rutrum ipsum purus id augue.
</div>

<div style="page-break-before:always;margin-top:40px;">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut dictum sapien at odio ullamcorper efficitur. Nam luctus tortor enim, id consequat ex scelerisque vel. Duis vulputate, sem et faucibus auctor, diam nisi fermentum risus, a viverra purus magna nec lorem. Cras efficitur vehicula elit, et suscipit sem varius vestibulum. Etiam et laoreet augue. Etiam nulla magna, molestie nec efficitur sed, dignissim placerat felis. Fusce posuere dignissim nunc, vitae rutrum nunc tristique id. Sed molestie mi nunc, eget molestie augue sollicitudin a. Phasellus et porttitor libero. Integer ac dolor quis libero posuere varius in sit amet nisl. Maecenas ac metus a sapien bibendum malesuada in eget diam. Donec facilisis mi vel tortor pulvinar gravida. Aenean auctor nisi et augue facilisis, pellentesque blandit augue malesuada. Etiam eu ipsum a nunc vehicula pellentesque id ac metus. Fusce tincidunt sed urna in hendrerit.

Nam feugiat et nisl ac consectetur. Nunc in tellus volutpat, pulvinar libero vitae, congue orci. Aenean sit amet porta odio. Integer enim ex, maximus vitae erat sit amet, lobortis aliquam enim. Ut at odio nec eros ornare bibendum. In eget urna molestie ante mattis elementum. Mauris id sodales quam, non aliquam quam. Mauris justo nulla, varius in libero eu, interdum convallis eros. Nam efficitur ornare neque non convallis. Donec massa orci, auctor id fringilla eget, aliquet in leo. Morbi at aliquet nisl, eget commodo neque. Vestibulum vestibulum mattis neque, eget porta lorem pellentesque cursus.

Proin quis lacus in leo consequat gravida. Aenean sed ornare arcu, vel rutrum mauris. Ut arcu lacus, tincidunt a enim et, commodo elementum mi. Donec metus neque, feugiat vitae commodo eget, ullamcorper vehicula lorem. Nunc tincidunt velit sapien, id commodo lacus pretium eu. Aliquam massa tellus, ultricies ac fermentum in, cursus eu ante. Suspendisse a augue pretium, posuere nibh id, vulputate tellus. Nunc vehicula orci ac nibh sagittis tincidunt. Morbi tempus ultricies turpis, eu ullamcorper nisi.

Cras ornare dignissim felis eu tristique. Quisque aliquam magna sed nisi ultricies placerat. Proin fringilla, quam viverra consequat interdum, mauris ex malesuada sapien, id venenatis ante felis eu odio. Donec ultrices consectetur varius. Ut vel odio lorem. Aliquam condimentum tempor tristique. Proin a risus malesuada, efficitur urna at, lacinia nibh. Pellentesque consequat vulputate lorem vitae tincidunt. Proin eu congue felis, venenatis ornare elit. Etiam at nulla quis enim maximus fermentum sit amet eu dui. Morbi vel tellus eu mauris tincidunt placerat vel laoreet magna. Morbi sit amet est sit amet libero auctor accumsan. Integer ut nulla at eros volutpat euismod. Ut ullamcorper porttitor porta.

Aliquam varius velit eget enim hendrerit convallis. Suspendisse sed faucibus nisi. Nulla rhoncus orci nulla, quis pellentesque dolor sollicitudin ac. Aenean ac tincidunt turpis. Vivamus interdum dolor nec sem gravida euismod. Vestibulum blandit erat nunc, vel gravida lacus lacinia eget. Morbi faucibus purus fermentum, faucibus libero sit amet, semper tellus. Integer molestie quam nec purus tristique, et tincidunt augue hendrerit. Proin sit amet dui in nulla vestibulum mattis et euismod nulla. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vivamus nisi sapien, faucibus ut tincidunt nec, rutrum in sem. Phasellus iaculis, ipsum eu ultricies fringilla, ligula felis imperdiet odio, vel rutrum ipsum purus id augue.
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This works for me.: i found a tutorial here https://ironpdf.com/docs/questions/edit-add-cover-page-csharp/

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am going to try this out and reply back with the results.

Comment: Something to note is that my html is being generated by depending on user input. This means that I can't add page-break-before or page-break-after to it since I don't know the user input length. As for the pdf merging solution ... that's what I am currently using ,but since I have to generate and merge 3 pdf documents it is:
1- Not efficient especially for big pdf files
2- I causes inconsistency between the merged pages. Ex. The content(or part of it) of the page before the last one is being duplicated in the last page too. Or maybe some small part of a content is missing.

Comment: page-break-before or page-break-after doesn't relate to adding headers/footers or margins through the html - it was used it to shorten the html content in the example.

Please can you elaborate on the issues you are seeing when trying to merge large PDFs? If you can email developers@ironsoftware.com with an example or use the contact form at http://ironpdf.com/, our engineers can investigate this for you further.