# C# - PDF Headers and Footers

Tags: c#, pdf, pdf-generation, html-to-pdf, ironpdf

I am using IronPDF to generate PDF documents in .NET.  I wish to have different headers on odd and even pages.

Based on all of the IronPDF API presented, The headers and footers should be the same on every page. **For example:**

```cs
using IronPdf;
 
 
IronPdf.ChromePdfRenderer Renderer = new IronPdf.ChromePdfRenderer();
 
// Add a header to every page easily
Renderer.RenderingOptions.FirstPageNumber = 1; // use 2 if a cover page  will be appended
Renderer.RenderingOptions.TextHeader.DrawDividerLine = true;
Renderer.RenderingOptions.TextHeader.CenterText = "{url}";
Renderer.RenderingOptions.TextHeader.FontFamily = "Helvetica,Arial";
Renderer.RenderingOptions.TextHeader.FontSize = 12;
 
// Add a footer too
Renderer.RenderingOptions.TextFooter.DrawDividerLine = true;
Renderer.RenderingOptions.TextFooter.FontFamily = "Arial";
Renderer.RenderingOptions.TextFooter.FontSize = 10;
Renderer.RenderingOptions.TextFooter.LeftText = "{date} {time}";
Renderer.RenderingOptions.TextFooter.RightText = "{page} of {total-pages}";
```

Source: https://ironpdf.com/tutorials/html-to-pdf/

Is there a way to alter this behavior so that I can have custom Headers and Footers on even and/or odd pages?
How about on specific pages such as only page 6 and 9?

Comment: Thanks for this question.  I have similar issues with wanting exact header / footer content to be specified on a per-page basis via IronPDF API

Answer (score 3):

```
// PM> Install-Package IronPdf


using IronPdf;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
 
 
//First create a PDF or Load an existing PDF using IronPdf.PdfDocument.Load()
var Renderer = new IronPdf.ChromePdfRenderer();
var multi_page_html = @"
            <p> This is 1st Page</p>
              <div style = 'page-break-after: always;' ></div>
              <p> This is 2nd Page</p>
            <div style = 'page-break-after: always;' ></div>
              <p> This is 3rd Page</p>
            <div style = 'page-break-after: always;' ></div>
              <p> This is 4th Page</p>
            <div style = 'page-break-after: always;' ></div>
              <p> This is 5th Page</p>
            <div style = 'page-break-after: always;' ></div>
              <p> This is 6th Page</p>
            <div style = 'page-break-after: always;' ></div>
              <p> This is 7th Page</p>";
 
using IronPdf.PdfDocument pdfdoc = Renderer.RenderHtmlAsPdf(multi_page_html);
 
 
// Create a Header
var header = new HtmlHeaderFooter();
header.HtmlFragment = "THIS IS HEADER {page} of {total-pages}";
 
 
// Create a Page Range  0 .. 7
var allPageIndexes = Enumerable.Range(0, pdfdoc.PageCount);
 
// Example 1
// Apply header to even page index only. (page number will be odd number because index start at 0 but page number start at 1)
var evenPageIndexes = allPageIndexes.Where(i => i % 2 == 0);
pdfdoc.AddHtmlHeaders(header, 1, evenPageIndexes);
pdfdoc.SaveAs("EvenPages.pdf");
 
 
// Example 2
//Apply header to odd page index only. (page number will be even number because index start at 0 but page number start at 1)
var oddPageIndexes = allPageIndexes.Where(i => i % 2 != 0);
pdfdoc.AddHtmlHeaders(header, 1, oddPageIndexes);
pdfdoc.SaveAs("OddPages.pdf");
```

Answer (score 0):

When rendering a PDF from HTML I agree that the Headers/Footers options are limited.

There is a Solution though: Add the headers and Footers AFTER the pdf has been rendered.

1. IronPDF rendering creates an `IronPDF.PdfDocument` class instance .
2. This `IronPDF.PdfDocument` class instance has methods to add Headers
   and Footers only to specific page numbers.

This approach supports adding both Text and HTML based headers to PDFs.

**MSDN Style Docs:**

- [IronPDF.PdfDocument.AddTextHeaders](https://ironpdf.com/object-reference/api/IronPdf.PdfDocument.html#IronPdf_PdfDocument_AddTextHeaders_IronPdf_TextHeaderFooter_System_Int32_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_Int32__)
- [IronPDF.PdfDocument.AddTextFooters](https://ironpdf.com/object-reference/api/IronPdf.PdfDocument.html#IronPdf_PdfDocument_AddTextFooters_IronPdf_TextHeaderFooter_System_Int32_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_Int32__)
- [IronPDF.PdfDocument.AddHtmlHeaders](https://ironpdf.com/object-reference/api/IronPdf.PdfDocument.html#IronPdf_PdfDocument_AddHtmlHeaders_IronPdf_HtmlHeaderFooter_System_Int32_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_Int32__)
- [IronPDF.PdfDocument.AddHtmlFooters](https://ironpdf.com/object-reference/api/IronPdf.PdfDocument.html#IronPdf_PdfDocument_AddHtmlFooters_IronPdf_HtmlHeaderFooter_System_Int32_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_Int32__)

Code Example:

```cs
// PM> Install-Package IronPdf
 
using IronPdf;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
 
 
//First create a PDF or Load an existing PDF using IronPdf.PdfDocument.Load()
var Renderer = new IronPdf.ChromePdfRenderer();
var multi_page_html = @"
            <p> This is 1st Page</p>
              <div style = 'page-break-after: always;' ></div>
              <p> This is 2nd Page</p>
            <div style = 'page-break-after: always;' ></div>
              <p> This is 3rd Page</p>
            <div style = 'page-break-after: always;' ></div>
              <p> This is 4th Page</p>
            <div style = 'page-break-after: always;' ></div>
              <p> This is 5th Page</p>
            <div style = 'page-break-after: always;' ></div>
              <p> This is 6th Page</p>
            <div style = 'page-break-after: always;' ></div>
              <p> This is 7th Page</p>";
 
using IronPdf.PdfDocument pdfdoc = Renderer.RenderHtmlAsPdf(multi_page_html);
 
 
// Create a Header
var header = new HtmlHeaderFooter();
header.HtmlFragment = "THIS IS HEADER {page} of {total-pages}";
 
 
// Create a Page Range  0 .. 7
var allPageIndexes = Enumerable.Range(0, pdfdoc.PageCount);
 
// Example 1
// Apply header to even page index only. (page number will be odd number because index start at 0 but page number start at 1)
var evenPageIndexes = allPageIndexes.Where(i => i % 2 == 0);
pdfdoc.AddHtmlHeaders(header, 1, evenPageIndexes);
pdfdoc.SaveAs("EvenPages.pdf");
 
 
// Example 2
//Apply header to odd page index only. (page number will be even number because index start at 0 but page number start at 1)
var oddPageIndexes = allPageIndexes.Where(i => i % 2 != 0);
pdfdoc.AddHtmlHeaders(header, 1, oddPageIndexes);
pdfdoc.SaveAs("OddPages.pdf");
 
 
// Example 3
// Apply header to last page only.
var lastPageIndex = new List<int>() { pdfdoc.PageCount - 1 };
pdfdoc.AddHtmlHeaders(header, 1, lastPageIndex);
pdfdoc.SaveAs("LastPageOnly.pdf");
 
// Example 4
// Apply header to first page only.
var firstPageIndex = new List<int>() { 0 };
pdfdoc.AddHtmlHeaders(header, 1, firstPageIndex);
pdfdoc.SaveAs("FirstPageOnly.pdf");
 
// Example 5
// Skip the first page.
var skipFirstPageIndexes = allPageIndexes.Skip(1);
var fileName = "SkipFirstPage.pdf";
pdfdoc.AddHtmlHeaders(header, 1, skipFirstPageIndexes);
pdfdoc.SaveAs("SkipFirstPage.pdf");
 
 
// Example 6
// Skip first page and make second pages label as 1.
 var skipFirstPageIndexes = allPageIndexes.Skip(1);
pdfdoc.AddHtmlHeaders(header, 0, skipFirstPageIndexes);
pdfdoc.SaveAs("SkipFirstPageAndDontCountIt.pdf");
```

Source: https://ironpdf.com/examples/adding-headers-and-footers-advanced/
Related Question (but not identical): [IronPdf - How to make headers and footers not cover page content when converting HTML to PDF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68637339/ironpdf-how-to-make-headers-and-footers-not-cover-page-content-when-converting)